# Replacing an oddly sized French Patio Door

Tags: repair, doors, framing, exterior, door-frame

Purchased a new home and working through the litany of issues with the place. Nothing undisclosed but just a royal pain in the ass. I have a leaky exterior door that needs to be replaced. It is a french door that only opens on one side. I wanted to switch to a double door in the process.

I pulled the molding off and took a measurement 66 1/2" by 81. So I hop on Lowes and Home Depot it is not even a filter option. Additional searching yielded nothing. I brought a contractor in and basically I have no wiggle room in term of size due to the exterior siding. I have other things to attend to and I do not want to spend a lot of money on this. How can I get a door that fits that opening. I want a pre-hung double door unit.

Any ideas?

Comment: *I pulled the molding off and took a measurement* what exactly did you measure? And what exactly did you search for? Doors generally come in nominal sizes intended for installation on a range of rough openings. If your 66 1/2" measurement was the rough opening, that's basically a nominal 64" door, which aren't the most common but definitely available in box stores (at least to order, if not in stock).

Comment: @dwizum The door is a pre-hung french door. My measurements matched the contractors which was 66 1/4 x 81. I think I am going to buy a 64 x 80 and call it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of 32" doors should fit easily. Any slop at the siding can be trimmed out with a piece that covers the existing siding.

Go to a real door place. They'll be able to give you a reasonable price for what you want/need. And if you need a deeper jamb for the aforementioned overlap strategy, they're equipped to deal with that. I've hated every big box store door I've had to touch over the last 5 years.

I'm a little surprised that your contractor didn't tell you all this. (Well, except for the rant about big box stores... that might just be me.)

ps, if you must search online, use "64x80" for a size.

Comment: The rant? It's not just you...

Comment: The "best" one was the door where they double-depth mortised the hinge into the jamb and face mounted it (crooked, of course) onto the door edge. Practical, I'll grant you, but still thoroughly appalling.